# Getting an error while importing Phone number Validator from the react-phone-number-input npm package

Tags: reactjs, validation, npm

I'm importing the phone number validator from the package into a checkout form on my page but it's showing this error when I refresh the page:

> "[libphonenumber-js] `metadata` argument was passed but it's not a
> valid metadata. Must be an object having `.countries` child object
> property. Got an object of shape: { default }."

Here is the Code Block of the Phone Validator

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'

function Phone() {
  // `value` will be the parsed phone number in E.164 format.
  // Example: "+12133734253".
  const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return (
    <PhoneInput
      placeholder="Enter phone number"
      value={value}
      onChange={setValue}/>
  )
}

export default Phone
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eb2auu?file=src%2FWebpages%2FRegister.js,src%2FComponents%2FPhone.js,src%2FWebpages%2FCheckout.js

^ This is a hosted version of the whole website/code.

I've tried to use a simple input tag as shown in the npm package as well as importing the phone input from the package directly into the checkout file rather than making a separate component to import and render into the checkout form and all of them are returning the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. But only on the production server, not the local dev server. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the version of `react-phone-number-input`, I downgraded to version `3.2.0` and the error is gone.

[Gitlab Issue: [3.2.1] (React-Hook-Form) Error [libphonenumber-js] `metadata` argument was passed but it's not a valid metadata.](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/-/issues/141)